# Why does the processing of |INDEX("__string__") filter fail on calling the executable jq-win32.exe from Windows commmand line?

Tags: batch-file, jq

If it's possible, I couldn't find the solution in the Internet.
I have JSON file:

```
{
    "ReferenceNumber": "d4fd41850323d2f6000000b013016327",
    "TimeoutInSec": 900,
    "RequestToUploadFileList": [
        {
            "BlobName": "8377ed3d-1b05-4c76-b718-6fddd46fd298",
            "FileName": "jpk_vat_100-01.xml.zip.aes",
            "Url": "https://taxdocumentstorage09tst.blob.core.windows.net/d4fd41850323d2f6000000b013016327/8377ed3d-1b05-4c76-b718-6fddd46fd298?sv=2015-07-08&sr=b&si=d4fd41850323d2f6000000b013016327&sig=yFXyJdsPPkbE0iQwVs5ccLEYEU0lxQHldbVyPfPciXw%3D",
            "Method": "PUT",
            "HeaderList": [
                {
                    "Key": "Content-MD5",
                    "Value": "eXkPLHMM+dHB5GCFoeAvsA=="
                },
                {
                    "Key": "x-ms-blob-type",
                    "Value": "BlockBlob"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "BlobName": "0a80a089-bc10-41e1-a74d-70fd45f27aa3",
            "FileName": "jpk_vat_100-02.xml.zip.aes",
            "Url": "https://taxdocumentstorage09tst.blob.core.windows.net/d4fd41850323d2f6000000b013016327/0a80a089-bc10-41e1-a74d-70fd45f27aa3?sv=2015-07-08&sr=b&si=d4fd41850323d2f6000000b013016327&sig=Fj%2BGjn7hCKIM6hSvMBGWBxSOyV7V%2FLMM9pnenbaoxks%3D",
            "Method": "PUT",
            "HeaderList": [
                {
                    "Key": "Content-MD5",
                    "Value": "NZew85QTb16mFLzx9cyKzA=="
                },
                {
                    "Key": "x-ms-blob-type",
                    "Value": "BlockBlob"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to split `RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url` into two parts: before `?sv=` and the remaining string.

I am trying to convert it into other JSON using Windows command line

```
c:\EJPK\exe>type "c:\TEMP\jpk1012\out\JPK_VAT.xml.sig.resp"| d:\curl\send\bin\jq-win32.exe -r "{ReferenceNumber:.ReferenceNumber} + {URI:(.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url)} + {URI_ABS:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url[0:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url|index("?sv=")] } +{URI_SAS:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url[.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url|index("?sv="):] } + {FILE:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].FileName} + {Key:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].HeaderList[0].Value}"
```

I am using a formula tested on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/YCMm9F0tnE).

Clearly the problem is in the filter concatenation or putting string into INDEX filter:

```
.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url|index("?sv=")
```

The source/original formula build with jqplay.org:

```
jq '{ReferenceNumber:.ReferenceNumber}
    + {URI:(.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url)}
    + {URI_ABS:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url[0:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url|index("?sv=")] }
    + {URI_SAS:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url[.RequestToUploadFileList[0].Url|index("?sv="):] }
    + {FILE:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].FileName} 
    + {Key:.RequestToUploadFileList[0].HeaderList[0].Value}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into problems because you're not following the quoting rules for the Windows/DOS command line.  You would probably find things simpler if you used jq's -f command-line option, which makes all those problems vanish.  You're running into these problems because your jq program includes double quotation marks.

Please also note:

1. jq's filter names are case sensitive, so that `INDEX` and `index` are quite different;
2. If you are going to use `index`, it would be better to use it just once, perhaps storing it as a jq variable;
3. Your jq program can be greatly simplified by "lifting" `.RequestToUploadFileList[0]`:

```
{ReferenceNumber:.ReferenceNumber}
 + (.RequestToUploadFileList[0]
    | (.Url|index("?sv=")) as $ix
    | {URI:.Url,
        URI_ABS: .Url[0:$ix],
        URI_SAS: .Url[$ix:],
        FILE: .FileName,
        Key: .HeaderList[0].Value } )
```

4. For robustness, you might want to deal with the case when $ix is null.
5. Instead of using `index`, you might wish to consider using `capture`:

```
(.Url|capture( "(?<head>.*)(?<tail>\\?sv=.*)" )) as $url ...
```

Comment: In the DOS realm retriving INDEX with command line should look like this `(.Url|index(\"?sv=\"))` and huge thanks for simplifying my "program".